# findAll() method in Grails not behaving properly when using "and" and "or" clauses

Tags: grails, closures, findall

Why the "and" and "or" clauses don't work inside the findAll() method in grails?

For instance, this code:

```
Student.findAll {
   and {
      name == "A"
      name ==~ "%A" 
   }
}.collect { it.name }
```

will generate the list:

```
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ']
```

which is wrong. It should have generated nothing. None of the records match the condition having the exact name “A” and an ending “A”. The string shown is listing ALL the records in my Student table.

It gets a little bit worse. This code:

```
Student.findAll {
   or {
      name == "A"
      name ==~ "%A" 
   }
}.collect { it.name }
```

generates the same list:

```
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ']
```

when in reality should have returned just the record “AA”.

Is there something wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use regular boolean operators in the criteria, e.g.:

```
Student.findAll {
    name == "A" && name ==~ "%A" 
}.collect { it.name }

Student.findAll {
    name == "A" || name ==~ "%A" 
}.collect { it.name }
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of found that solution but would like to know the reasons behind. Why "and" and "or" don't work?

Comment: The `findAll` criteria use the expression syntax introduced with `where` queries rather than the criteria builder.

Comment: Shouldn't Grails complaint about the use of the clauses at some point? It's really causing bugs hard to find. Thanks for your help!